# How would I avoid spending my Bitcoins when I need to buy a house quickly?

Tags: payment, sell-bitcoins, value, fiat, lending

A specific house I would like to buy has come up for sale. This opportunity is unlikely to arise again.

I have almost enough money in Bitcoin to buy the house.

I have no other money or assets sufficient for the purchase.

I do not wish to spend my money or transfer control of my money to a third party

How can I buy the house?

Comment: ,،so what is your problem ? If we can help you How much time do you have?
how much do you have to pay for the house?
How mach your bitcoin?

Comment: My problem is how to get the house without having to waste my Bitcoin in my situation. If there is a solution. I doubt there is, but I'm desperate.

Comment: If you feel that this house right now if worth spending your BTC for, then you should do so. Otherwise, don't, or buy another. Nobody can make that decision for you.

Comment: If you want to buy something without spending your BTC, you'll need to spend other money.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to take out a loan on your Bitcoin like how Ethereum can be used as a CDP in the MakerDAO to get DAI?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88882/is-there-a-way-to-take-out-a-loan-on-your-bitcoin-like-how-ethereum-can-be-used)

Comment: As usual, the "Does this answer your question?" question does not answer my question...

Comment: I have edited your question in an attempt to prevent its deletion. I believe the edited form reflects the essence of your question. If you object to the edits, please click the "edited..." link and select "rollback".

Answer (score 2):

The essential character of money is that you transfer it (or control over it) to another person in exchange for some object or service.

There is no way to use money to purchase something and still retain the money.

None of the alternatives are acceptable to you for various reasons

- Rent
- Mortgage
- Invest money in a business and defer purchase until investment returns exceed purchase prices

Bitcoin is money.

Therefore your problem is insoluble. You cannot have your cake and eat it.